# Barplot becoming stacked when I try to map custom colours to each group in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, palette

I want to produce a horizontal grouped barplot using `ggplot2`. Data are grouped by `Name`, each `Name` has one `Color` and two `School`, which should be visualized with different transparencies (`Alpha`). I have put all the data I need into my data frame (`test`).

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- structure(list(Name = c("Jean", "Jean", "Mike", "Mike", "Ruth", 
                                "Ruth", "Elia", "Elia", "Jess", "Jess"), 
                       School = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
                       Value = c(11L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 27L, 22L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L), 
                       Color = c("#E55C30FF", "#E55C30FF","#FBB91FFF", "#FBB91FFF", "#FCFFA4FF", "#FCFFA4FF", "#C7E8AC", "#C7E8AC", "#228B22", "#228B22"),
                       Alpha = c(0.9, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4,0.9, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

test

   Name School Value     Color Alpha
1  Jean      A    11 #E55C30FF   0.9
2  Jean      B     8 #E55C30FF   0.4
3  Mike      A    15 #FBB91FFF   0.9
4  Mike      B    16 #FBB91FFF   0.4
5  Ruth      A    27 #FCFFA4FF   0.9
6  Ruth      B    22 #FCFFA4FF   0.4
7  Elia      A     0   #C7E8AC   0.9
8  Elia      B     4   #C7E8AC   0.4
9  Jess      A     0   #228B22   0.9
10 Jess      B     3   #228B22   0.4
```

I am struggling with mapping the right color to each group. This is my code so far, which achieves the grouping, the plot being horizontal, the transparency, and the grey contouring. But I cannot map each color to each group.

```
ggplot(test, 
       aes(y = Name, x = Value, fill = School, alpha = Alpha)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "grey50") +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

I tried adding `fill = df$Color` inside `geom_bar()`, I also tried to change it to a factor (`fill = as.factor(df$Color)`) but the bars become stacked instead of staying grouped. I still have troubles understanding `ggplot2` syntax and I guess I am overlooking something simple here...

**EDIT:** what I would like to change is the filling of the bars, where each `Name` should have its own filling (according to the `Name` itself, as specified in `df$Color`), and then a different transparency to distinguish between `School`.

Comment: It looks like there's a small mistake in your code. Instead of using fill = School in the aes argument, you should use color = Color. Also, you don't need to use fill = df$Color inside geom_bar() since you have already specified fill = School in the main aes argument. I wrote code below

Comment: Thank you Umar. As `ggplot2` distinguishes between `color` and `fill`, I do realize my question was unclear. What I want to change is actually the filling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `scale_alpha_manual` allows you to map alpha values to schools (without using the `alpha` column in the data frame).  The problem is then what should the legend look like since all the bars are different colours?  You'd probably have to add a label to each bar.

```
ggplot(test, 
       aes(y = Name, x = Value, fill = Color,alpha=School)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_identity() + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c("A"=0.9, "B"=0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks George, I got lost somewhere easy. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Following your code I have used similar approach where, I used both fill = School and alpha = Alpha in the main aes argument, making transparency dependent on the "Alpha" column. Fill colors are determined by the "School" variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(test, 
       aes(y = Name, x = Value, fill = School, alpha = Alpha, color = Color)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + #optionla ,color = "grey50" can be kept inside bracket here
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "#E55C30FF", "B" = "#FBB91FFF")) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: I explained in comment

Comment: .good one, +1..